# Creating a forum with a CMS (Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress etc.), and using that forum in a spring MVC web application

Tags: java, wordpress, spring, spring-mvc, content-management-system

I'm working with spring MVC doing web application. This application is almost complete but I want to add a forum to that web application. I heard that doing a forum with a CMS is rather easy, so my question is:

*Is it possible to do that forum with a CMS, like Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, etc., and when I finish doing the forum with one or any other CMS, add that forum to my spring MVC web application?*

I never have done this before so I don't know if it's possible to do it, and if it's possible how this will affect my spring MVC project. I'm working with spring tools suite.

I also looking for spring packages or APIs, or java APIs, libraries etc., like jForum or any other, to do it without a CMS, but there's not much information. Where should I start looking..?

EDITED

i hava a table Users in a oracle database that i use in my spring mvc application since i have a user's module and its work is to crate,modify and delete users and  i would like to use the same data from that users table in the forum

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No. There's no easy way of doing this.

The long answer is: It depends on the level of integration you need.

If you just want show a forum which does not share any data with your spring application, this isn't to difficult. Just emebed the forum in an iframe. Or even simpler: provide a link.

Likely you want to share user or any other data (think of users). This isn't easy since you have to share this data between two different applications running on different plattforms. That is of course possible, but does not come for free.

To get a better answer you have to tell us more about your spring application and what kind of data you like to share between the forum and your application.